# Solr: DocValuesField appears more than once in this document (Solr 6.5)

Tags: solr

Receiving this error after upgrading to Solr 6.5 when I attempt to insert a record into the field.

**Full Error:**

```
2017-06-05 02:57:40,685 ERROR 
[org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient] - Request to collection 
<collection> failed due to (400)
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error 
from server at http://<host>:8983/solr/<collection>: Exception 
writing document id <number> to the index; possible analysis error: 
DocValuesField "location_field_0_coordinate" appears 
more than once in this document (only one value is allowed per field)
```

**Field Declaration:**

```
<field name="location_field" type="locations" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

**Type Declaration (location):**

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, `solr.LatLonType` does not support multivalued fields.

It appears in Solr **6.5** there was a change to check for the condition of inserting multiple values into a `solr.LatLonType`.

In Solr **6.3** I am able to successfully insert multiple locations into a `solr.LatLonType` field type.

**Solution:**
you should replace your `location` field type with `LatLonPointSpatialField`, which is a drop in replacement to `solr.LatLonType` that supports multivalued fields.

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true"/>
```

See: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search